# Need support to properly query my DB when a lot different data are coming into play

Tags: mysql

Suppose you have this schema:

[image: Schema example]

Of course it's over-simplified in this example, just pretend you have a collection of users, that are described with a lot of different tables like the ones drawn here.

You can assume that:

- Any user have a **name**,
- Any user can speak one or more **languages**
- Any user can own one or more **titles** or **certifications**
- Any user can own one or more **experiences**

Suppose that you have to show this large amount of data to a third user, that needs to nimbly access, **search** and administrate this (great) amount of data with ease.

**What is done:**

My first approach was to show just the most relevant infos of each users, to provide a first clean interface where the admin could start from, and allow him  to filter the records shown, using all the data available on the DB.

To cut a long story short, the admin can (or should be able to) "display all **male** users that speak **english** and worked for **IBM**" on screen, while seeing just a clean and simplified list of records, that he'll be able to examine further in a different way if he needs to.

**How my query look like:**

```
SELECT
users.id as id,
name,
surname,
etc,
certificazioni.title as certifications,
lingue.language as language,
esperienze.company,
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN lingue ON users.id = lingue.iduser 
LEFT JOIN certificazioni ON users.id = certificazioni.iduser 
LEFT JOIN esperienze ON users.id = esperienze.iduser 
GROUP BY users.id 
ORDER BY users.id
```

I Built an interface that given some user input, is able to append conditions to this query like this:

WHERE language = 'English' AND Sex = 'm'

**Now the problem:**

With this query i'm able to find out if is there a certain user that speak English, is male and so on, but it fails to find out if is there a users that **speaks both English and Dutch** to say one.

**Why?**

*(From my point of view)* It's because *(i'm failing to find a good approach, AND because)* of the relations between *users* and other tables, that are one to many in most cases and causes the output of this query to be something like that:

without GROUP BY

```
ID NAME  SEX LANGUAGE COMPANY
-----------------------------
12 Alamo M   English  IBM
12 Alamo M   Italian  NBA
12 Alamo M   Dutch    NULL
12 Alamo M   French   NULL
```

(Combination of every different value of each language, experience and so on)

with GROUP BY

```
ID NAME  SEX LANGUAGE COMPANY
-----------------------------
12 Alamo M   Italian  NBA
```

(That are of course flatted with evident loose of information with the group by function)

**Now the requirement:**

My need is to find a different approach to this problem that consider the limits i'm imposed to have, and still allow me to efficiently query my DB in most cases.

I'm also uploading a screen of the platform, to better describe what kind of user input i expect:

[image: Some user inputs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use a subquery for each condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE
    users.id IN (SELECT users_id FROM lingue WHERE language = 'English')
    AND
    users.id IN (SELECT users_id FROM lingue WHERE language = 'Dutch')
    AND
    ...
```

Comment: I'm still testing your solution, i'm not 100% sure it will work in any possibile case, but until now it appear to be a faster and cleaner than other approaches.

Comment: I've found your solution more adaptable in my context.
Thanks to all of you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is not trivial. For each language/skill/certification condition you add to a query you need to (inner) join another table. Note that when the same table appears more than once, each instance must have its own alias, and you can use group_concat to put multiple input row values on the same output row e.g.

```
Select u,name, group_concat(c.title)
From users u
Inner join lingue l1
On u.id=l1.user_Id
And l1.language='Italian'
Inner join lingue l2
On l1,user_Id=l2.user_id
And l2.language='French'
Inner join certificazioni c
On u.id=c.user_id
Group by u.name
```

Lists names and qualifications of people whom speak both French and Italian, and have at least one qualification. But you may find it simpler to denormalise the database into one or two tables and use full text search.

Comment: Ok, i've tried your first suggestion by adding another **JOIN** wherever the users needs to apply multiple single field condition, like *Speaks both French and Italian*, and it works like a charm, and yet, don't you think that this approach could be too much expensive anyway? I've got 19 records for each single user in some cases.

**Could exist a cleaner solution?**

Can you explain further your second suggest in practical? **denormalise the database into one or two tables and use full text search**